# How to vertical center align and title and radio buttons

Tags: jquery-mobile, radio-button

I am trying to make a simple profile page for an app i'm trying to put together.

It has 4 questions, the last of which is `Gender`.

The other three questions worked well with "field container text inputs," but i wanted to use radio buttons for the gender question.

When I try to align the `Male/Female` buttons with the `Gender` title they always are too close and not inline with the title.

What I'm trying to achieve is getting the buttons inline with `Gender` and at the same distance as the other three sections.

Here is what I have so far:

```html
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
       <label for="height" style="font-size:25px"><strong>Height</strong></label>
       <input style="display: inline-block;  width: 5%" type="text" name="name" id="height" value="" />
       <p style="display: inline-block; margin-left:5px; margin-right:10px"> feet   </p>
       <input style="display: inline-block;  width: 5%" type="text" name="name" id="height" value="" />
       <p style="display: inline-block; margin-left:5px; margin-right:10px"> inches OR   </p>
       <input style="display: inline-block;  width: 5%" type="text" name="name" id="height" value="" />
       <p style="display: inline-block; margin-left:5px"> cm</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
       <label for="height" style="font-size:25px"><strong>Height</strong></label>
       <input style="display: inline-block;  width: 5%" type="text" name="name" id="height" value="" />
       <p style="display: inline-block; margin-left:5px; margin-right:10px"> pounds OR   </p>
       <input style="display: inline-block;  width: 5%" type="text" name="name" id="height" value="" />
       <p style="display: inline-block; margin-left:5px"> kg</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
       <label for="age" style="font-size:25px"><strong>Age</strong></label>
       <input style="width: 5%" type="text" name="name" id="age" value="" />
    </div>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
       <div style="display:inline !important;">
          <label style="font-size:25px"><strong>Gender</strong></label>
       </div>
       <div style="display:inline-block !important; float:right !important;">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="male" value="choice-1" />
          <label for="male">Male</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="female" value="choice-2" />
          <label for="female">Female</label>
       </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change markup for Gender field group to following:

```html
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <legend><strong style="font-size:25px">Gender</strong></legend>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="male" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
        <label for="male">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="female" value="choice-2" />
        <label for="female">Female</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: @Agustin Feliciano Did it help?

Comment: THnaks a lot that looks really good, but is there any way to keep the word "Gender" a <label>?  This would help me keep everything easier to format

Comment: Now [`<legend>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-legend-element.html#the-legend-element) and [`<label>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-label-element.html#the-label-element) semantically have different purpose.  `<legend>` element represents a caption for it's parent `<fieldset>` element. And it's exactly what you have here. So even if that would be possible (and it is using CSS) I would **strongly discourage** you from doing that.